# Database table as a job queue for multiple instances

Tags: sql, database, concurrency, jobs

Let's say I have a table with some jobs that need to be executed, that is read by many instances of the same service.
I have a status column, and each instance is querying first row which is not taken yet (filtering by status) and then changing this status within the same transaction.

How do I prevent multiple instances reading the same job and then updating its status and executing it simultaneously?

Comment: You lock the table when you are running the queries.

Comment: Is it efficient to lock the whole table? Is there no better way?

Comment: . . Databases have lots of different locking methods.  However, the specifics usually depends on the database.  My comment was generic because your question is generic.